# Simple query taking long time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a query on a table and looking at the query statistics.  It is executing very slowly once it hits a certain point.

Is there some sort of over-complication here I am missing? I have done much more complicated queries and joins, and they have taken seconds maximum.  This is going to take hours.

I am using SQL Server 2017

```
drop table if exists #barcodestemp
select 
    suc.stock_code,
    suc.suc_unit_desc,
    case 
        when not exists (select * from nicholas.dbo.stock_unit_conversion suc2 where suc2.trade_unit_no = suc.trade_unit_no and suc2.stock_code != suc.stock_code)
        then 
            suc.trade_unit_no
        else 
            ''
        end as barcode
into
    #barcodestemp
from nicholas.dbo.stock_unit_conversion suc
```

and the execution plan

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryVTnTHsn

Comment: Hi, is this what you mean ? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryVTnTHsn

Comment: check if the table indexes are good, doesnt solve all your problems but can help

Comment: The 2 table scans will definitely cause slowness.  Put index on your search columns.

Comment: And you can probably avoid a second reference to the same table by using a window function to check for duplicates.

Comment: How would I use a window function to with the same paramaters as the not exists ?

Comment: How can i check all other rows of the table with the window function and the where conditions of the subquery ? Can you use where clause on partition by ?

Comment: Half a million rows merge-joined to another half a million rows will take time. [checktheplan](https://checktheplan.com/?p=b677f05bb7ea4e41abc82a9724ba8e6f&l=st). Are you sure there's no filtering condition in your query? It returns 530k rows.

Comment: The merge join is "many to many" on `trade_unit_no` - does your data have many rows with the same `trade_unit_no`? You could be getting large cross joins if so

Comment: That looks like the only explanation (other than waits) for catastrophic slowness leading you to conclude "This is going to take hours"

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes there are about 5000~ rows with the same trade_unit_no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

500K rows (with estimated row size of 71 bytes) is pretty small. Unless your query is blocked or you are heavily resource constrained SQL Server should generally be able to deal with that size of data in worst case seconds - if you get the impression "This is going to take hours" and the query is busy rather than waiting you need to look for areas of potential quadratic complexity.

The merge join is "[many to many](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/merge-join/ba-p/383133)" - this means that you can end up getting some fairly large cross joins if you have many rows with the same `trade_unit_no` - as in this example data.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.stock_unit_conversion(trade_unit_no INT, stock_code UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, suc_unit_desc VARCHAR(1))

INSERT dbo.stock_unit_conversion 
SELECT TOP 500000 1, NEWID(), ''
FROM sys.all_columns c1, sys.all_columns c2


select 
    suc.stock_code,
    suc.suc_unit_desc,
    case 
        when not exists (select * from dbo.stock_unit_conversion suc2 where suc2.trade_unit_no = suc.trade_unit_no and suc2.stock_code != suc.stock_code)
        then 
            suc.trade_unit_no
        else 
            ''
        end as barcode
from dbo.stock_unit_conversion suc
option (merge join)
```

The above executes extremely slowly as the merge join on one side needs to store all the rows with the duplicate `trade_unit_no` in a work table and continually replay them. As the join is a semi join you might expect that it doesn't have to replay **all** the duplicates as it can stop as soon as it finds the first one matching `suc2.stock_code != suc.stock_code` but in reality it appears that it does end up doing the complete replay for every row and then applies the residual predicate at the end of all that.

After 3 minutes on my machine with this "worst case" data the query wasn't even 1% done and had only output 1.1K rows out of 500K.

[image]

The following rewrite should cope with this case much better

```
SELECT stock_code,
       suc_unit_desc,
       barcode = CASE WHEN MIN(stock_code) OVER ( PARTITION BY trade_unit_no) = stock_code
                       AND MAX(stock_code) OVER ( PARTITION BY trade_unit_no) = stock_code THEN trade_unit_no
                   ELSE ''
                 END
INTO   #barcodestemp
FROM   dbo.stock_unit_conversion
```

[image]

Comment: Wow this worked great. Can you elaborate on how the case statement and min() max() works so I can use this going forward for other use cases. Thank you

Comment: @nicholas8855 - this sorts the rows by `trade_unit_no` once - then uses that ordering to know all the rows belonging to a particular  `trade_unit_no` are together and it can spool a partition, calculate the `MIN(stock_code)` /`MAX(stock_code)` over that partition then add those values back into the spooled rows. So this doesn't have the same problem as the equijoin on `trade_unit_no`  of increasing work quadratically when you have some `trade_unit_no` with many rows. It is much more linear. If the min/max `stock_code` in the partition are the same there is only one value in the partition

Comment: I have assumed that `stock_code` isn't nullable BTW - if it is nullable it might need a tweak

Comment: `CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY trade_unit_no) = 1 THEN trade_unit_no` seems more idiomatic, and possibly faster. That obviously assumes `trade_unit_no, stock_code` is a unique key in the table.

Comment: @nicholas8855 It's called a window function https://www.brentozar.com/sql-syntax-examples/window-function-examples-sql-server/

Comment: @MartinSmith No stock_code is never null, this worked perfect thank you!